The graph from prometheus shows nothing, query errors
I just installed node_exporter, prometheus and grafana in that way. On the first EC2 instance with Jenkins i installed Prometheus and Grafana and in the second instance with Tomcat i installed node_exporter.I have some errors. When i try to query for example node_cpu_seconds_total in prometheus i get this error:
Error executing query: Expected ',' or ']' after array element in JSON at position 530 (line 1 column 531)
Also in grafana for node exporter full i have these errors :
Templating
Failed to upgrade legacy queries e.replace is not a function
Templating [job]
Error updating options: e.replace is not a function
Templating [node]
Error updating options: e.replace is not a function
I will attach photos too. Any help?enter image description here
enter image description here

You probably have multiple metrics named node_cpu_seconds_total and you need probably only one of them. Try to run the guide at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/ and you will see that by typing prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds you also get the same error but when typing prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds{quantile="0.99"} it works OK

There is some issue with 2.52.0-rc.1. I reverted back to older version 2.45.5 and it works fine

Thanks Score Pandit, saw it also now. Relevant link https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/14040

For me, the problem was when going over the guide at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/, I've encountered the same error when typing only prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds.
When looking at http://localhost:9090/metrics I've noticed that indeed prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds has 5 metrics,
prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds{interval="15s",quantile="0.01"} 14.999437041
prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds{interval="15s",quantile="0.05"} 14.999437041
prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds{interval="15s",quantile="0.5"} 15.000015625
prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds{interval="15s",quantile="0.9"} 15.001391959
prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds{interval="15s",quantile="0.99"} 15.001391959

Once I've changed to any of the typed above examples, e.g. prometheus_target_interval_length_seconds{quantile="0.99"} it worked
